# Reading pairs of image files at once

Tags: python, image, opencv, operating-system, computer-vision

So, I'm looping through a directory and trying to read some image files, as follows:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
            im1 = cv2.imread(file)
```

How can I read a **pair** of images at once? Such that, in the above code, I have something like:

```
im2 = cv2.imread(file)
```

where the `file` here represents the immediate image that comes after the first image.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

**To process pair of files:**

```
import os
import itertools

path = "SRC PATH"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file1, file2 in itertools.izip_longest(files[::2], files[1::2]):
        im1 = cv2.imread(file1)
        if file2:
            im2 = cv2.imread(file2)
```

I use the **[izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)** method just incase if you only have odd number of files in your dir.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. If I print files[::2] and files[1::2], I get the following, respectively: ['a.1.jpg', 'a.3.jpg']
['a.2.jpg', 'a.4.jpg']. How can I get the results in order, for instance  ['a.1.jpg', 'a.2.jpg'] and ['a.3.jpg', 'a.4.jpg']?

Comment: @Simplicity. That is correct. If you print after the loop you can see the files are 'a.1.jpg', 'a.2.jpg'. Try: for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file1, file2 in itertools.izip_longest(files[::2], files[1::2]): print file1, fiel2